# Sending xml data from one server to another

Tags: asp.net, xml

Can anyone tell me the best way to send some xml data from one server to another in an asp.net application.

Basically in one application on a certain condition I want to trigger the sending of some xml values to another receiving asp.net application that will process the data and return the user to the sending site.

If anyone has any other simpler javascript/url/html type solution I would also be interested to hear that.

---

The situation is I need to send a few pieces of information from the sending site to our server for processing - ideally it needs to be secure.

The values will be from a shopping cart, such as price, merchantid and email address.

We will be providing the code to the cart owner to add to their site, so the simpler the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a web service on the target server that is consumed by the client server.  It might be simpler to just create a page on the target server that accepts the xml in an http POST.  Then the client server could send the data using an HttpWebRequest.

Here's an explanation of how to use HttpWebRequest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Creating a web service on your receiving asp.net application would probably be your best bet.  You could also do a simple Ajax call perhaps.  It really depends on your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/) or Web Services.